# Python: Jupyter: How select a specific string in a Dict & List. conventional methods aren't working

Tags: python, list, api, dictionary, jupyter

Good day Everyone, I am getting Data from an API that looks like this . .

```
BalR= c.get_balances(assets)
print(BalR)

{'balance': [{'account_id': '619619619619', 'asset': 'LUX', 'balance': '17639852741.00', 'reserved': '619619', 'unconfirmed': '619619'}]}
```

I am trying to attach just the float of this `'balance': '17639852741.00'` to this variable `BalR`, this is what I've tried so far . . .

```
array2=[]
for i in BalR:
    if "balance" in i:
        array2.append(i)
print(array2)

['balance']

for key, value in BalR.items():
    print(key, ' : ', value)

{'balance': [{'account_id': '619619619619', 'asset': 'LUX', 'balance': '17639852741.00', 'reserved': '619619', 'unconfirmed': '619619'}]}

print(BalR['balance'])

{'balance': [{'account_id': '619619619619', 'asset': 'LUX', 'balance': '17639852741.00', 'reserved': '619619', 'unconfirmed': '619619'}]}

for k, v in BalR.items():
    if k == 'balance':
        print(v)
{'balance': [{'account_id': '619619619619', 'asset': 'LUX', 'balance': '17639852741.00', 'reserved': '619619', 'unconfirmed': '619619'}]}

for k, v in BalR.balance():
    if k == 'balance':
        print(v)
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-0885ed5d34e7> in <module>
----> 1 for k, v in BalR.balance():
      2     if k == 'balance':
      3         print(v)

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'balance'

print(BalR.balance[2])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-a6a9f44f2008> in <module>
----> 1 print(BalR.balance[2])

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'balance'
```

please advise.

Comment: `BalR['balance'][0]['balance']`?

Comment: mozway, I've been battling with this for a long time. you solved it straight away Thank you, it Worked.. Could You please explain why it worked?

Comment: I'm not sure what to explain, you just walk step by step, dictionary key->item ; list index->item ; dictionary key->item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a list within your dict, you should get the first item on the list and then use the key from the inside dict.

```
BalR = {'balance': [{'account_id': '619619619619', 'asset': 'LUX', 
'balance': '17639852741.00', 'reserved': '619619', 'unconfirmed': '619619'}]}
BalR['balance'][0]['balance']
'17639852741.00'
```

Also, I recommend you to use list comprehension if you have more than one dictionary inside balance.

Comment: Oh ok, I understand now. Thank you Alex!